# What does "communication enthusiast" mean?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

As I screen profiles of candidates, I have come across the term "communication enthusiast" used by candidates to describe them. Something like this: "A communication enthusiast who is experienced in ...".

To me, this term does not make sense. The word "communication" to me so so vague and does not give enough insight. When I see the term "communication enthusiast", questions like what kind of communication arises.

However, I understand things like "digital communication enthusiast".

Does using "communication enthusiast" to describe oneself on a resume or job portals make sense?

Answer (score 4):

It is largely meaningless.  CVs, resumés and personal statements are littered with such terms. Everybody is "passionate about [debugging OCaml]" or "a motivated and creative [full-stack programmer]". These are CV clichés

Yes, the candidate says that they are enthusiastic about communication.  Probably that means they think that they are effective writers and speakers. It is an open invitation to an interviewer to question them. If you do interview them, you might ask "You say you are a 'communication enthusiast'.  How will you use that to bring value to our company?"

It doesn't mean much, and it isn't a red flag.  But
Perhaps they've been to a CV writing course and said that one can't put "I spend every free movement on my mobile", but you can put "communication enthusiast".

Answer (score -1):

I searched the term on the Internet and based on the examples I saw, it seems to me that a communication enthusiast is someone who is very interested in communicating with people. The nature of the communication could be anything. It could be about marketing or even about science in a scientific community. Someone who is a communication enthusiast seems to be interested in effective ways of communication with a specific group of people (or even with people in general) depending on the scope of their communication. Naturally, they try to learn a lot of words and be good at grammar and care about their choice of words so as to make their communication as effective as possible.